# Sorting a list containing objects from a Reference class in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to sort a list which contains objects from a Reference Class. I want to sort it according to the attribute Tmax. How can I do it?

```
node <- setRefClass("node", fields = list(P1 = 'numeric', P2 = 'numeric', PrS = 'numeric',
                                          Fmin = 'numeric', Fmax = 'numeric', Tmin = 'numeric',
                                          Tmax = 'numeric', v1 = 'character', v2 = 'character',
                                          x1 = 'numeric', x2 = 'numeric'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider having:

```
your_list[order(sapply(your_list, function(x) x$Tmax), decreasing = TRUE)]
```